# Please clarify vagrant behavior

Tags: vagrant

I have just started working with Vagrant. After starting guest machine and making some changes (e.g. installed some updates and python virtualenvs). And after few (`vagrant halt` and `vagrant reload`) when I ssh-ed into guest machine I noticed that all my changes disappeared. When I opened the Virtualbox I saw that there were two boxes with the name of my folder with guest os and on every `vagrant up` it seems like it is starting the second machine. When I started the first guest os through virtual box interface I saw that my data was present. How can I start with vagrant the first machine? Should I delete the second? When was it created?

Start with `vagrant up`

Vagrantfile

```
Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
  config.vm.box = "trusty_14"
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 8000, host: 8000
end`
```

Comment: Could you please post your vagrant file and how you invoke it?

Comment: waouh, thats weird, did you attempt to destroy the machine once ? can you check the file `<yourproject>/.vagrant/machines/default/virtualbox/id` and make sure it has the Id value as the first VM machine ? you can find id value of the vm by checking the vbox file of the VM or running the command `VBoxManage list vms`

Answer (score 0):

So I tried to `vagrant destroy`. The second machine was deleted indeed, but after `vagrant up` the new one was created.

Then I checked the id's following @Frédéric Henri advice, and in `id` file was id of second machine, so I have replaced it with the id of first machine from `VBoxManage list vms`, and everything works!
But still did not get how and when the second machine was created...